# IntelliJ shortcut to define variables matching the method call

Tags: intellij-idea

I frequently find myself in a situtation where I want to call a method which takes numerous arguments and I want these arguments to be defined as local variables.

Let's say I have:

```
class MyService { 
  MyService(String arg1, Integer arg2, Long arg3) { }
}
```

now I type:

```
new MyService(
```

and I want Intellij to generate:

```
String arg1 = null;
Integer arg2 = null;
Long arg3 = null;
new MyService(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Is there a way how this can be done in IntelliJ?

Comment: For the current moment there is no such a feature, please feel free to create one at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues